# Clustering unique datasets based on similarities (equality)

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I just entered into the space of data mining, machine learning and clustering. I'm having special problem, and do not know which technique to use it for solving it.

I want to perform clustering of observations (objects or whatever) on specific data format. All variables in each observation is numeric. My data input looks like this:

1   2   3   4   5   6

1   3   5   7

2   9   10  11  12  13  14

45  1   22  23  24

Let's say that **n** represent row (observation, or 1D vector,..) and **m** represents column (variable index in each vector). **n** could be very large number, and **0 < m < 100**. Also main point is that same observation (row) cannot have identical values (in 1st row, one value could appear only once).

So, I want to somehow perform clustering where I'll put observations in one cluster based on number of identical values which contain each row/observation.

If there are two rows like:

1

1 2 3 4 5

They should be clustered in same cluster, if there are no match than for sure not. Also number of each rows in one cluster should not go above 100.

Sick problem..? If not, just for info that I didn't mention time dimension. But let's skip that for now.

So, any directions from you guys,

Thanks and best regards,
JDK

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to recommend anything since your problem is totally vague, and we have no information on the data. Data mining (and in particular *explorative* techniques like clustering) is *all* about understanding the data. So we cannot provide the ultimate answer.

Two things for you to consider:
1. if the data indicates presence of species or traits, Jaccard similarity (and other set based metrics) are worth a try.
2. if absence is less informative, maybe you should be mining association rules, not clusters

Either way, without understanding your data these numbers are as good as random numbers. You can easily cluster random numbers, and spend weeks to get the best useless result!

Comment: Thanks for answer! My data is exactly that data above. My one input is list of numbers from 0 to 281474976710655 (2^48), and in the list can be up to 100 variables. I'm having millions of those lists as my dataset, so I want perform some kind of clustering (or other technique) where I want to group those lists based on variables and match of variables between lists. Simple as that.

Comment: But what do the numbers mean? No matter how they are *stored*, they must have a meaning, or your are bound to fail.

Comment: Ofc that they are having meaning ... They are representing "point". That point is unique in space domain. One entity is getting up to 100 of those points, so I'm trying to cluster entities based on similarity between their points. So entity A can have points 1, 2, 3, entity B can have points 3, 4 and entity C can have 4, 5. So there is link between A and C, and in this case they should be clustered together. Now imagine that there are millions of entities and 2^48 points which are distributed in those entities... Also FYI I found Jaccard similarity as good start.. Not sure is it enough...

Answer (score 1):

Can your problem be treated as a Bag-of-words model, where each article  (observation row) has no more than 100 terms?

Anyway, I think your have to give more information and examples about "why" and "how" you want to cluster these data. For example, we have:

```
1 2 3
2 3 4
2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4
3 4 6
6 7 8
9 10
9 11
10 12 13 14
```

What is your expected clustering? How many clusters are there in this clustering? Only two clusters?

Before you give more information, according to you current description, I think you do not need a cluster algorithm, but a structure of connected components. The first round you process the dataset to get the information of connected components, and you need a second round to check each row belong to which connected components. Take the example above, first round:

```
1 2 3   : 1 <- 1, 1 <- 2, 1 <- 3 (all point linked to the smallest point to
          represent they are belong to the same cluster of the smallest point)
2 3 4   : 2 <- 4 (2 and 3 have already linked to 1 which is <= 2, so they do
          not need to change)
2 3 4 5 : 2 <- 5
1 2 3 4 : 1 <- 4 (in fact this change are not essential because we have
          1 <- 2 <- 4, but change this can speed up the second round)
3 4 6   : 3 <- 6
6 7 8   : 6 <- 7, 6 <- 8
9 10    : 9 <- 9, 9 <- 10
9 11    : 9 <- 11
10 11 12 13 14 : 10 <- 12, 10 <- 13, 10 <- 14
```

Now we have a forest structure to represent the connected components of points. The second round you can easily pick up one point in each row (the smallest one is the best) and trace its root in the forest. The rows which have the same root are in the same, in your words, cluster. For example:

```
1 2 3   : 1 <- 1, cluster root 1
2 3 4 5 : 1 <- 1 <- 2, cluster root 1
6 7 8   : 1 <- 1 <- 3 <- 6, cluster root 1
9 10    : 9 <- 9, cluster root 9
10 11 12 13 14 : 9 <- 9 <- 10, cluster root 9
```

This process takes *O(k)* space where *k* is the number of points, and *O(nm + nh)* time, where *r* is the height of the forest structure, where *r* << *m*.
I am not sure if this is the result you want.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Not sure about "Bag of words", because I'm having distinct numbers in each row. Thing is that there can be more than 1000 rows(entities) which are having same variable inside. And they should be in same cluster, but I want to have only 100 of them in same cluster. So some kind of better similarities should be accounted for that case. Answ: I'm clustering rows(entites) which are having same variables inside and rule is not to have more than 100 entities in one cluster. Number of clusters are unknown, because number of rows is very variable, (and values inside each row).

Comment: Maybe try some hierarchical clustering algorithm. They can continue separating a large cluster into small clusters. I think you can try to modify one to continue separating until the size of each cluster < 100. The used similarity can be the Jaccard similarity, or you can find one in this paper:
http://www.iiisci.org/Journal/CV$/sci/pdfs/GS315JG.pdf